# using .htaccess, is there a way to allow access to a file only if current date is between 2 dates

Tags: .htaccess

For a company campaign, we want a page to be available only between 2 datess. There a way to allow access to a file only if current date is between 2 dates using .htaccess??

Comment: `mod_rewrite` could do that by using a regular expression to match a time and then a `RewriteRule` with `F`, I reckon.

Comment: how do i get date & tme in the rewrite rule?

Comment: Depends on the environment, but environment variables seem like the best take on this. Alternatively use a simple script that does the distinction, gets transparently put in front using a `RewriteRule` and returns the HTTP status for forbidden when the campaign is over and the contents of some file/folder otherwise. Need to run, this is why I commented and didn't write an answer :)

Comment: ok, you gave me some ideas on where to look. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) has various TIME variable which you could use in a `RewriteCond` directive. Based on [this post](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/date-conditional-redirects-with-mod_rewrite/) the following works:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME} <20120607000000
RewriteRule /specialpage - [F]

RewriteCond %{TIME} >20120609000000
RewriteRule /specialpage - [F]
```